# How to use request and session scopes in spring-webflux (as of latest releases)

Tags: spring-webflux

I am developing a rest web service using reactive programming through spring-webflux(`Spring Boot 2.1` and `Spring Framework 5.1`). I need to create components having request level scope. @Scope annotation is suggested for spring MVC applications. But I found that the same doesn't work with webflux application.

Is there an equivalent feature available in webflux, as of latest release?

If not, what shall be the workaround here to create a new instance of a component on every incoming request?

I am trying to avoid use of new operator.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use request scopes in `spring-webflux` like in spring MVC applications. The main reason being, they use ThreadLocals which cannot be used by `spring-webflux` as work can be done on any thread at any time.

Spring webflux uses `project-reactor` at its core. So you can use [Reactor Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) which allows you to share data in your reactive pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chip in, this is an example of how I had to fix it with Webflux/Kotlin:

```
// Old code (no longer working): RequestScope does not work with webflux (relies on ThreadLocal)
@Bean
@RequestScope
fun session(repository: Repository): Session {
    return SessionImpl(repository)
}

// alternative, note: this does not leverage the IoC-container, which means that you can not take the Session as a constructor dependency
@Bean
fun session(repository: Repository): WebFilter =
    object : CoWebFilter() {
        override suspend fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: CoWebFilterChain) {
            withContext(SessionImpl(repository).asCoroutineContext()) {
                chain.filter(exchange)
            }
        }
    }
```

And instead of constructor dependency you have to access your stateful service by:

```
// suspend function:
val session = currentCoroutineContext().session()
```

The context extension:

```
class SessionContextElement(
    val session: Session,
) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(Key) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<SessionContextElement>
}

suspend fun CoroutineContext.session(): Session {
    return currentCoroutineContext()[SessionContextElement.Key]?.session ?: throw Error("Session has not been intialized!")
}

fun Session.asCoroutineContext(): SessionContextElement {
    return SessionContextElement(this)
}
```

Please note: this requires Spring Boot 3.2 which supports changing the coroutine context in CoWebFilter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27522